# ¿Como puedo hacer que me salga un mensaje cuando en usuario ingrese mal la contraseña en PHP (Entorno web)?

Tags: php, html, html5

Estoy tratando de enviar un mensaje al usuario cuando ingrese un correo existente, pero solo he logrado que cuando ingrese el mismo correo redireccione a una pagina y muestre un mensaje alert, pero quiero que solo muestre el mensaje alert (o otra forma) y no vuelva a recargar la pagina por que cuando se recarga la pagina se pierden todos los datos que ha ingresado el usuario, haciéndolo que tenga que ingresar todo nuevamente, ese es mi problema dado que se hace engorroso tener que ingresar todos los datos nuevamente ya que son muchos

```
<?php

$Correo=$_POST['Correo'];
$Contraseña=$_POST['Contraseña'];
$Pais=$_POST['Pais'];
$Nombre=$_POST['Nombre'];
$Apellido=$_POST['Apellido'];
$PreguntaS=$_POST['PreguntaS'];
$Rsecreta=$_POST['Rsecreta'];
$DiaN=$_POST['DiaN'];
$MesN=$_POST['MesN'];
$AñoN=$_POST['AñoN'];


$nombre_servidor = "127.0.0.1";
$nombre_usuario = "root";
$password = "";
$nombre_bd = "users";

/***** Crear Conexion ****/

$Conexion = mysqli_connect ($nombre_servidor, $nombre_usuario, $password, $nombre_bd);

/***** revisar Conexion ****/
if (!$Conexion) {
    die("La conexión falló: " . mysqli_connect_error());
   }

/***** Consultar si existe un correo igual al que se quiere registrar ****/

$stmt = $Conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios where Correo = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $Correo);
$stmt->execute();

$resultado = $stmt->get_result();

/***** Si el numero de filas es mayor a 0 usuario registrado. mantener el registro ****/

if ($resultado->num_rows > 0) {
    
/* Esto es lo que quiero evitar */

    echo "<script>
      alert('Correo ya registrado');
      window.location = 'Login.html';
    </script>";

/***** Si correo no existe registrar datos ****/
}else{
    $stmtIn = $Conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (Correo , Contraseña , Pais , Nombre , Apellido , Pregunta_S , Respuesta_S , Dia_N , Mes_N , Año_N)
     VALUES (? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?)");

    $stmtIn->bind_param("ssssssssss", $Correo, $Contraseña, $Pais, $Nombre, $Apellido, $PreguntaS , $Rsecreta , $DiaN , $MesN, $AñoN);
    $stmtIn->execute();
    header('location:Login.html');

}

/***** Cerrar conexion y sentencias preparadas ****/
$stmtIn->close();
$stmt->close();
$Conexion->close();

?>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Registro</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Estilos.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="FormularioRegistro" class="Formulario" >
        
    <form action="V-Registro.php" method="POST">
      
        
        <select name="Pais" id="Pais" class="Selec_100">
            <option value="Chile">Chile</option>
        </select>

        <input type="text" id="Nombre" name="Nombre" placeholder="Nombre" class="I-MEDIO" required>
        <input type="text" id="Apellido" name="Apellido" placeholder="Apellido" class="I-MEDIO" required>
        <input type="text" id="DiaN" name="DiaN" placeholder="Dia de nacimiento" class="Input_30" required>

        <select name="MesN" class="Select_30" >
               <option hidden selected>Mes</option>
               <option value="Enero">Enero</option>
               <option value="Febrero">Febrero</option>
               <option value="Marzo">Marzo</option>
               <option value="Abril">Abril</option>
               <option value="Mayo">Mayo</option>
               <option value="Junio">Junio</option>
               <option value="Julio">Julio</option>
               <option value="Agosto">Agosto</option>
               <option value="Septiembre">Septiembre</option>
               <option value="Octubre">Octubre</option>
               <option value="Noviembre">Noviembre</option>
               <option value="Diciembre">Diciembre</option>
        </select>

        <input type="text" id="AñoN" name="AñoN" placeholder="Año" class="Input_30" >
        <input type="email" id="Correo" name="Correo" placeholder="Direccion Correo electronico" class="I-COMPLETO" required>
        <input type="password" id="Contraseña" name="Contraseña" placeholder="Contraseña" class="I-COMPLETO" required>

        <select name="PreguntaS" id="PreguntaS" class="Selec_100" >
            <option hidden selected>Seleccione una pregunta</option>
            <option value="¿Lugar de nacimiento?">¿Lugar de nacimiento?</option>            
        </select>

        <input type="text"  name="Rsecreta" placeholder="Respuesta secreta" class="I-COMPLETO" required>

        <input type="submit" id="CrearCU" value="Crear cuenta gratuita" class="BotonCeleste , SUBMI-COMPLETO">
        <input type="button" onclick="location.href='Login.html'" value="¿Ya tienes cuenta?" class="BotonNegro , SUBMI-COMPLETO">
    </form>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: llama a tu url de destino con un parametro GET en el que esta ultima esta programada para saber que hacer en caso de recibir un determinado parametro GET

Answer (score 0):

Si lo quieres hacer rápido te diría que en la página del formulario del login añadas el siguiente código PHP:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET["loginincorrect"])) {
   <script>
     alert("Usuario o password incorrecto");
   </script>
}
?>

...
```

Y donde evaluas el usuario y password envias de vuelta el nombre del html pero por ejemplo:

```
header("location: login.html?loginincorrect=1");
```

AL final haces que por el metodo HTTP GET envias en la la URL Query la variable *loginincorrer a tu formulario de login que tiene que mostrar un alert de JS indicando que el usuario o el password está mal.

PD: Una recomendación, no uses Ñ, en su lugar utiliza anyo, anio o similar.

Saludos!

Comment: Exacto como decia yo, es facil y rapido

Comment: si lo que pasa es que como envío todos los datos, soi estamos hablando de un formulario con muchos datos, no solo login

Comment: Solo quiero que salga un mensaje emergente sin cambiar la pagina, nada mas

Comment: me dijieron que podria hacerlo con javaScript

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias formas de evitar que se recargue la pagina al tratar de enviar un formulario y asi la informcion no se pierda, Por medio de AJAX, inyecciones HTTP...

Por AJAX seria una forma mas dinamica para realizar lo que tratas de hacer.